# Hear Yamaha P45 with headphones connected to a computer

Tags: piano, computer, headphones

I've seen posts about recording with a computer, don't know much about music so i prefered asking the question myself.
Can i plug a P45 to my computer, and then use headphones (connected to the computer) to hear the P45 piano (without the piano making any sound on his own audio system, so that the sound of the piano only comes from the headphones that are connected to the computer) ?
Thanks a lot ! This will help me a lot :)

Comment: Why do you need to do this? You will introduce latency [delay on the throughput sound]

Comment: I want to do this cause my headset needs an USB dongle to work... And i don't know if i can plug it into the P45.

Answer (score 3):

Here is your manual: https://www.musikkhandel.no/media/files/2496/p45_en_om_a0.pdf

According to your manual you have a headphone jack on the keyboard itself which deactivates the speakers so if you only want to hear the keyboard through headphones there is no need to go thorough the computer, all you need is a pair of headphones that have a 1/4” jack or a 1/4” adapter for whatever headphones you have.

The usb connection is MIDI only so you can transmit MIDI to your computer then use the computer’s software sounds to hear what you play.

If you want to also record the audio from your piano you can hear the Yamaha piano sound through the computer by plugging the output (headphone) jack into the computer via an audio interface (separate purchase) using the necessary adapters (preferred method) or a 1/4” to mini stereo cable directly from the keyboard into the computer (not nearly as good, reduced audio quality) and then running it into a DAW.

Comment: I would like to turn the speakers on and off while the headphone jack is plugged in. Do you know how to do that @John Belzaguy?

Comment: With these keyboards and a lot of other gear plugging in headphones automatically turns off the speakers. Aside from having it modified for that purpose I know of no way to independently turn the speakers on and off while leaving the headphone jack in.